# Custom validation directive does not work

Tags: validation, angularjs, typeahead

I have a input field with typeahead in html form as shown below

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"><br/>
```

Typeahead values will be loaded form js as shown below

```
   $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi'];
```

This is working as expected. But i need a validation to check the input value is selected from states lookup or not. Any help could be appreciated.

see demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/QLfP6d5a9Xj97TAv5l66?p=preview

Comment: Hi! Can you get an example on jsFiddle or Plunkr?

Comment: Hi Aaron, here is the example. http://plnkr.co/edit/1WBThmckBBSBZ68kSjkR?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `typeahead-on-select` property.

```
<input ... typeahead-on-select='onSelect($model)'>
```

And add a callback function in the controller:

```
$scope.onSelect = function ($model) {
    console.log("Selected", $model);
};
```

<kbd>**[See the demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbTmFBh0rw9rXI6jS0AE?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: sza, i think my question is not clear. See the Plunkr link below. There is button in disabled mode and it should get enabled or valid only when input value is selected from lookup states.
  http://plnkr.co/edit/QLfP6d5a9Xj97TAv5l66?p=preview